# How to run open-source software on remote Linux server?

Tags: linux

I am playing around with [an open-source software, FSL](http://fsl.fmrib.ox.ac.uk/fsl/fslwiki/). I have no problems running it on my Mac, where I am able to simply start it by typing `fsl` in the terminal.

However, I have no idea how to start the software on our school's HPC server. After logging into the school server via SSH, I type `fsl` as usual, and then

```
If 'fsl' is not a typo you can run the following command to lookup the package that contains the binary:
    command-not-found fsl
-bash: fsl: command not found
```

Then, I navigate into the FSL installation directory (`/data/apps/arch/Linux_x86_64/fsl/5.0.6`) and type `fsl`. Still the same error. I have also tried

`module load /data/apps/arch/Linux_x86_64/fsl/5.0.6`

But this error occurs.

```
utility.c(2360):ERROR:50: Cannot open file '' for 'reading'
utility.c(2360):ERROR:50: Cannot open file '' for 'reading'
...
```

How should I load it properly and ultimately run it?

Comment: Try `./fsl` in the install directory. On linux, `.` is not in path by default.

Comment: @urzeit strangely, there is no executable called `fsl` in the install directory. I `ls` that directory, there are `bin    build.log  data  etc     include  LICENCE  refdoc  tcl
build  config     doc   extras  lib      README   src` only.

Comment: Have a look in the `bin` dir.

Comment: @urzeit Indeed it is there. Thank you so much! One follow-up question: it seems that I do NOT have to cd into the .../bin folder every time in order to start the software. Why is i so? I mean, how does the system know which executable I wish to start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call the executable with the correct path. You may either

- `cd` to the directory containing the executable
- prefix the executable's name with the path `./fsl`

or (if you intend to use the executable frequently):

- add the executable's path to your `PATH`-environment variable (`export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/the/folder/containing/the/executable`)
- use the executable's name to call it (`fsl`).

or you place a symlink to your executable somewhere the `$PATH` already points to:

- Check `$PATH` with `echo ${PATH}` (outputs a colon-separated list of directories the command line processor will look for your call)
- If there is `~/bin` in there, place a symlink: `ln -s /path/to/your/executable/fsl ~/bin/fsl`.

The command line processor will search the directories listed in `${PATH}` for an executable called `somecommand` if you type `somecommand`.